# Load issue on IE due to use to datatable destroy usage to recreate the table on using filters

Tags: jquery, datatables

There is a load issue on IE and we see a long running script error due to the below code.

I am trying to recreate the datatable using destroy when selecting filters or resetting it, but somehow it is slowing the process. I have 1000 records now, but it will increase with time.

Please can you provide me an alternate for datatable.destroy().
I don't want to use table.ajax.reload() as this is not the solution in my case.

```
$(id).DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    searching: true,
    paging: true,
    ordering: false,
    "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
});

$("#btnSearch").click(function (e) {
    resetClicked = false;
    var uri = window.location.href.toString();
    if (uri.indexOf("?") > 0) {
        var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("?"));
        window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
    }
    TableRecreate("#records_table");
});

var trHTML = '';
var getFromURL = '';
var totalJobs = '';
getFromURL = apiJobsURL;
$.ajax({
    url: getFromURL,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {},
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            trHTML += BindJobTable(item);
        });
        $('#records_table').append(trHTML);
    }
});
```